# How to write a generic type with constraint extending iterable with Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write this kind of type:

```
type Pagination<I extends Iterable> = Readonly<{
  seek: number;
  limit: number;
  total: number;
  items: I;
}>;
```

So that way users can use:

```
Pagination<Map<number, any>>
```

But it appears this doesn't work because `Iterable` also requires the a generic parameter.

So instead I'm left with

```
type Pagination<I> = Readonly<{
  seek: number;
  limit: number;
  total: number;
  items: Iterable<I>;
}>;
```

Although this works as well, type signatures now become `Pagination<number>` with no way to further constrain exactly what kind of iterable should be used.

Comment: You could make it `type Pagination<I extends Iterable<any>> = Readonly<{ /*...*/ items: I }>`.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That's the answer! Please submit an answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic parameter for the iterable itself instead of the item type, with `T extends Iterable<any>`

```
type Pagination<I extends Iterable<any>> = Readonly<{
  seek: number;
  limit: number;
  total: number;
  items: I;
}>;
```

**Note**: if you need the item type for some reason you could use a conditional type to extract it:

```
type Pagination<I extends Iterable<any>> = Readonly<{
  seek: number;
  limit: number;
  total: number;
  items: I;
  current: I extends Iterable<infer Item> ? Item: never
}>;

declare let map: Pagination<Map<string, number>>
map.current // [string, number]

declare let arr: Pagination<string[]>
arr.current // string
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwJYDs7CQexQHgJJQQAewEKAJgM5R6kBOcARgDYQ5wogB8XUAvFABKEOOWzMQOAN4AoKFEoQIAawBcUFAFcAtowh0A3HKjMk2pMHVbd+o-OCZgcZlZ17DxixG2V1eO1AAxpp0dGSWNIQkZFQ09EysOKgAZvpx3rwA-OnaVhAAbvoyAL5cRjLkEIHMcGEmEMBQ2nBg6vDIaBjYOACyLTiUwHSoCAA0Gm76PDLNYAB0waHhUAD0K1AA2oPDKGMTNnQAujIVVTV1rI21dG2IqOhYuNsjG4dcMtcLIWEojWsKQxGQA)

Comment: Does `current` act like a reified type? In that value cannot exist, so is it just used to help parameterize other functions that needs the internal item type?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Not sure I understand your comment. The type of current item is not defined relative to `T`, so if `T` is an `Iterable` (which it will be becuase of other constrains) we get the `Item` of the iterable. This is can be done indeed to help parameterize other functions that need the item type